# (Sumo cloze passage) What in tarnation was I supposed to put in this blank?

Tags: grammar, words, interrogatives

I was given the following cloze passage with 9 questions. Blanks 3, 6, 7 and 8 have *[requirements in brackets]* that must be followed when answering. I have filled in my **own answers in bold**.

While all other blanks were marked correct, I was marked as incorrect for blank 3. **Is いつ a valid answer? Why or why not?**

---

僕の名前は宇良和輝。１７歳で、仕事は **(1) 日本の大切な文化を守る人の** 一つとして有名な相撲。**(2)上手になる** ために **(3) いつ** *[Wh-Question]* も一生懸命に頑張っています。毎日 **(4) 練習して** ばかりで疲れてしまいますが、**(5)睡眠** さえ **取れ** ば、すぐ元気になります。怖い先輩もいて、**(6)しかられ** *[Passive]* たり、**(7)お茶をいれさせられ**
 *[Causative-Passive]* たりして、いやになるときもありますが、新しい友達もでき、一緒に **(8)助け** *[to help]* 合っています。大変ですが、相撲の **(9)大変さ** はやった人にしかわからないと思います。僕はがんばりますよ、横綱になるまでは。

Comment: Perhaps because you filled a wh-*word* instead of wh-*question*? And is it true that your answer #1 was marked correct?

Comment: Yes it was... do you think it is unnatural?

Comment: I think (1) is incorrect and (3) is correct. My answer for (1) is 「日本の大切な文化を守る（伝統的）スポーツの」

Comment: @rhyaeris As mackygoo said, 相撲 isn't a 人 but a sport.

Comment: @broccoliforest also 「守る人の一*つ*」is off, it would be 一人

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I do believe いつ there is *a* correct/valid answer. いつ meaning a WH-Question for "when" would fit here as in いつも (always)

Perhaps however, this was not the expected answer. Perhaps it was 「だれ」meaning here everyone is doing their best.

Comment: つまり「上手になるために**だれも**一生懸命に頑張っています」になる、ってことですかね・・・？